# Pagination in Version 1.3.2.3

Tags: custom-options, products, pagination, magento-1.3

Good afternoon, have me paged Order Magento One section, in which sample a list of products. The problem is that this shows the products as seen in the photo.

[image]

I wish to stay with pagination, But Magento version is 1.3.2.3. So I can not install widgets.
How do I?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not that you can't install widgets, the problem is your current Magento version. Magento 1.3 has been released in 2009, so it's really outdated. Also, it's known that this version (and other versions except the latest Magento 1.9 version) have a lot of security issues. So it's not recommended to keep using this version anymore, since your webshop can be skimmed, hacked, etc. pretty easily.

That's why I'd advise you to upgrade (or start over) using the latest Magento 1.9 (or maybe even 2.1) version. It will make your webshop much more secure and gives you a lot more features then you have now.

If you want to keep using your current database, you might want to read my comment [this question on StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103500/cli-upgrade-of-1-3-2-4-to-1-9-not-working/158212#158212).